# Unresolved external symbol referenced in main

Tags: c, visual-studio, function, syntax

I have to create a program that  has a function charster() that accepts three arguments: a character and two integers. It will print he character input x number of times per y number of lines. I am getting syntax error LNK2019 and LNK1120 Unresolved external symbol referenced in main. And IDK what I have done to cause this or what to do to correct it.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void charster(char n, int n_char, int n_lines);

int main(void)
{
    char n;
    int n_lines, n_chars;

    printf("Please enter a character to be printed, the amount of times it should appear, and the amount of lines that should appear: ");

    while (scanf("%c, %d, %d", &n, &n_chars, &n_lines) == 3)
    {
        charster(n, n_chars, n_lines);
    }
    return 0;


    void charster(char n, int n_char, int n_lines);
    {
        int count; 

        for (count = 0; count < n_lines; count++)
        {
            putchar(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is malformed. C does not support nested function definitions.

Comment: So I should move the function above main?

Comment: Yes. Or below, since you have a proper prototype.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, I have the function below main. "void charster(char n, int n_char, int n_lines);"

Comment: No, this function is *inside* of main. Before the closing `}` of `main`.

Comment: I have indented the code to make this more obvious. I presume it's just a typo, if you thought the function was separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly C language does not support nested functions. So you have to write the function **charster()** outside the main function.

You can write it above or below the main function as prototype is already declared.

Kindly have a look at the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void charster(char n, int n_char, int n_lines);

int main(void)
{
    char n;
    int n_lines, n_chars;

    printf("Please enter a character to be printed, the amount of times it should appear, and the amount of lines that should appear: ");

    while (scanf("%c %d %d", &n, &n_chars, &n_lines) == 3)
    {
        charster(n, n_chars, n_lines);
    }
    return 0;
}

void charster(char n, int n_char, int n_lines)
{
    int times; 
    int lines;
    for (lines = 0; lines < n_lines; lines++)
    {
        for(times=0;times<n_char;times++){
            printf("%c ", n);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I corrected that, now I have a C2449 found { at file scope (missing function header)

Comment: Alright I guess that was just in error, I was able to get it to compile. However it produces no output.

Comment: @Eysaak working on it. Just give me few more seconds

Comment: @Eysaak, Kindly check that I have corrected the scanf() syntax and also logically rectified the code. If that solves your issue, it will be great. Kindly mark the correct correct if you are satisfied.

Comment: Try with input c 2 3

Comment: This is the answer to the question you asked. If you have problems with the program logic - it is not related to *this* question.